# DownloadManager broadcasts DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE multiple times

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I started using android DownloadManager and noticed that when a download completes I get between 2-4 broadcasts of ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE and each is with reason STATUS_SUCCESSFUL for the same download ID....its smells like a bug?
is there a solution for this?

thanks.

Comment: Related/dupe: [DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast receiver receiving same download id more than once with different download statuses  in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8937817)

Answer (score 0):

This was the exact issue i faced back then

> Seeing this as well. For me it's like this:
>
> Download is started and seems to complete ok, I get the
>   DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED broadcast. However, right after this I see
>   DownloadManager logging:
>
> I/DownloadManager( 5893): Initiating request for download 1419
>   W/DownloadManager( 5893): Aborting request for download 1419: Trying
>   to resume a download that can't be resumed
>
> Then I get another DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED with the same download ID. Also,
>   it seems the downloaded file gets deleted during this second, failed
>   attempt.
>
> Any ideas what triggers this? Or any workarounds? Or is everyone just
>   writing their own download managers...

Reported to google; [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18462#c13)

I tried to figure out a way to work around this issue. But it was hard and costed alot. So i threw away all my work with `DownloadManager` and started coding my custom downloader. `DownloadManager` back then proved to be a pain.

A solution suggested for the issue is to use [this](https://github.com/yingyixu/android-download-manager) free, open source third party downloader in github

I'm not sure that it will work as you expect, it might have the same problem. I didn't try, but i hope it helps