# Finding download complete from downloadManager in android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am downloading a file to the device external storage from my android app from a web server using `DownloadManager`. I need to initiate another function on completion of this download. my file download code goes like this:

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.105/download/file.ext";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "files.ext");
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
```

please suggest how to get something like `onDownloadComplete`.....

Comment: can `downloadId` be used to know when download completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer at : [DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast receiver receiving same download id more than once with different download statuses  in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937817/downloadmanager-action-download-complete-broadcast-receiver-receiving-same-downl)
and the code for me goes like this:

```
private boolean downloadComplete(long downloadId){
        DownloadManager dMgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Cursor c= dMgr.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

            if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){
                return true; //Download completed, celebrate
            }else{
                int reason = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
                Log.d(TAG, "Download not correct, status [" + status + "] reason [" + reason + "]");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) with BroadcastReceiver

```
public class DonwloadCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // get complete download id
        long completeDownloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        // to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there is some reported bug in it, see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18462

Answer (score 0):

```
registerReceiver(onComplete,
                 new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Refer to [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java)